# override onbackPressed() by another's activity default

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activities. 
**MyMain
MySecond** I call MySecond activity in MyMain activity. And what i want, that when pressing back button in MySecond activity, it doesn't return to MyMain activity, but return to the screen where MyMain activity was called. I found a way to ovverride it, so it just opens home screen by this:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
      Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(setIntent); 
        return;
 }
```

Comment: Couldn't you `finish()` the MyMain activity when starting MySecond? That way closing MySecond would take you to the activity which originally launched MyMain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

That will move not only the current activity but all activities in your task (which would be your app) to the back of the activity stack. It should then return you to wherever you were before your MyMain activity started.